# How to create Gitlab issue from Redmine

Tags: gitlab, redmine, issue-tracking, redmine-plugins, gitlab-api

Is that possible to create a new Gitlab issue from Redmine?
I meant when we create a Redmine issue it will automatically create an issue in Gitlab.
So in this case, our client will create an issue from Redmine and that issue will be handle with our developer in the Gitlab issue.

Maybe you guys have an idea.

Many Thanks